# How to implement KTX updateLayoutParams() extension

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-extension

How do I add the KTX [updateLayoutParams()](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.view/android.view.-view-group/update-layout-params.html) extension to my project?

When I use it, Android Studio says "Unresolved reference: updateLayoutParams" even though I added this to gradle:

```
implementation ("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0")
```

I also rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need

```
import androidx.core.view.updateLayoutParams
```

This worked for me. I found this [here](https://gist.github.com/petedoyle/5e1a9791eab8a819c37f3ed849540e0d#file-systemwindowinsetextensions-kt)